# C# Using value from Listbox1 for SQL Query to filter Listbox2

Tags: c#, sql, selectedvalue

I have three SQL Tables - Team (Id, Name), Player (Id, Name) and TeamPlayer (Id, TeamID, PlayerID). I also have two ListBoxes on my Form and want to filter the 2nd ListBox when an Item is selected on the 1st ListBox.

This is mostly setup but I'm having issues where the code is not liking the value being passed to it in the LstTeams_SelectedIndexChanged method at the commented lines.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        showTeams();
    }

    private void showTeams()
    {
        // Create the SQL Query, and an SqlDataAdapter using this query and sqlConnection declared earlier
        string query = "select * from Team";
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);

        // Get the 'Team' Table and Fill it
        DataTable teamTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(teamTable);

        // Populate the 'Team' ListBox with the 'Team' Table
        lstTeams.DataSource = teamTable.DefaultView;
        lstTeams.DisplayMember = "Name";
        lstTeams.ValueMember = "Id";
    }

    private void LstTeams_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string TeamID = lstTeams.GetItemText(lstTeams.SelectedValue);
        MessageBox.Show("TeamID: " + TeamID);

        // Create the SQL Query, and an SqlDataAdapter using this query and sqlConnection declared earlier
        string query = "select * from Player p inner join TeamPlayer tp on p.Id = tp.PlayerID where tp.TeamID = @TeamID";

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamID", lstTeams.SelectedValue); // this
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand); // causes the dataadapter to error

        // Get the 'Team' Table and Fill it
        DataTable teamTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(teamTable);

        // Populate the 'Team' ListBox with the 'Team' Table
        lstPlayers.DataSource = teamTable.DefaultView;
        lstPlayers.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
```

My Error is:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type.'
```

I've looked up some solutions but have been unable to get a working result.

Thank you for any help provided :).

Comment: You mapped a DataSource so the SelectedValue is going to be a DataRowView object.  You need to cast it to a number.  And dont use AddWithValue

Comment: Use your variable `TeamID` for your param value, but you need to cast it as an `int` first if the column is an `int`. Also specify the datatype for your param type.

Answer (score 1):

After further research and some direction from comments made to my question, I have found success with the following:

```
DataRowView data = lstTeams.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
int TeamID = int.Parse(data["Id"].ToString());

string query = "select * from Player p inner join TeamPlayer tp on p.Id = tp.PlayerID where tp.TeamID = " + TeamID;
```

Inside the ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged method.